# Do we want a tag for German language?

Tags: discussion, tags

Right now the tag [germany](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) has a description that says it is only for the country and not the language, but German was used in many countries outside Germany, so perhaps the tag should be edited or a new one added, such as German-Language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if it's used for questions about the German language as it relates to genealogy.

We have the [latin](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) tag – I believe the only language tag currently – which has usage guidance:

> For questions about interpreting or translating genealogical records
>   written in Latin

Something similar for the German language would suffice.

For any new tags created please write a brief usage guidance.

At this stage, in my opinion we should avoid very locale specific tags such as [status-animarum](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-animarum) and [kurrent](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kurrent). The latter would be better tagged [german-language](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-language). I don't think we want a tag for every style of handwriting that ever existed; indeed it is often difficult to assign a particular script unambiguously to one specific category. *Status animarum* is a type of vital record, so would be better tagged [vital-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vital-records).

Tags are for grouping questions together in a useful way, not for pigeonholing them.

---

Previous post of mine relating to this topic (there may be others):
[Better defining the palaeography, transcriptions, translation, language(?) tags?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/better-defining-the-palaeography-transcriptions-translation-language-tags)

Comment: I agree with all your points here but will also link https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1888 which advocated language tags for a different reason.  That related to LOTE questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a reasonable idea (which can be generalised for other record langauges). However, I'd prefer to tag with [german-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-records) to make it clear that it's about understanding/interpreting records in German rather than about the language itself.

Comment: 'German records' sounds to me like records from Germany, and I doubt many people would read the usage guidance to appreciate the distinction between records in German vs records from Germany. It seems a waste of 3 tags to tag [tag:Germany], say [tag:birth-records], and [tag:german-records], when the first two really suffice. Of course, the same could be said of [tag:german-language] however the name of the tag makes it more clear that it is referring to the language.

Comment: What about Swizerland and German-records? (Or indeed USA and German-records as I understand some churches in America kept their recordsin German).  However, I think we're only disagreeing on the name of the tag, not its utility.

Comment: @HarryVervet [With longer tag names allowable now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297386/215590) perhaps a tag of [tag:german-language-records] would reflect precisely what we want to convey.

Comment: @Polygeo One problem with longer tag names is that they can reduce the 'real estate' on (e.g.) Google search results -- the most popular tag on a question is prepended to the question title -- probably not an issue for this particular tage but we need to think before we extend some tag lengths.

Comment: I'd not considered that but I think it just means that we should only use them when we really need to.

Comment: For the case @ColeValleyGirl posed in the comments, why not Switzerland + German + birth-records?

Comment: @JanMurphy Yes, if we adopt a "German" tag for the language -- tag for the place, the record-type and the language.